Schur's lemma when we have multiplicities
Let $\frak{g}$ be a simple Lie algebra and let $V$ be a simple finite-dimensional $\frak{g}$-module. We know from Schur's lemma that the dimension of $\frak{g}$-module maps from $V$ to itself is $1$.
For any integer $n>0$ it should hold that dimension of the space of module maps from
$$
V^{\oplus d} \to V^{\oplus d}
$$
is $d^2$. However I cannot prove this. I looked at the hom-sets
$$
\mathrm{Hom}(V^{\oplus d}, V^{\oplus d})
$$
and I guess that
$$
\mathrm{Hom}(V^{\oplus d}, V^{\oplus d}) \simeq \mathrm{Hom}(V,V)^{\oplus d^2} = d^2,
$$
but it is not clear to me that I am allowed to perform the first isomorphism. Can somebody confirm if this is correct?

You tag "abelian categories" yourself, and there are very general statements in those how Hom's commute with direct sums or direct products (aka coproducts and products), or turn one into the other, in their first or second component, respectively. Since you have finite multiplicities here, where direct sum and direct product are isomorphic, everything should be nice.

A general fact: for $V$ module we have
$$\operatorname{End}(V^{\oplus d}) \simeq M_d(\operatorname{End}(V))$$
where $M_d(R)$ is the ring of $d\times d$ matrices over $R$.
